# Could not find com.github.AmityCo.Amity-Social-Cloud-SDK-Android:amity-push-fcm:6.10.0

Tags: push-notification, chat

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeArundevReleaseArtProfile'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:arundevReleaseRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.AmityCo.Amity-Social-Cloud-SDK-Android:amity-push-fcm:6.10.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/AmityCo/Amity-Social-Cloud-SDK-Android/amity-push-fcm/6.10.0/amity-push-fcm-6.10.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/AmityCo/Amity-Social-Cloud-SDK-Android/amity-push-fcm/6.10.0/amity-push-fcm-6.10.0.pom
> - https://jitpack.io/com/github/AmityCo/Amity-Social-Cloud-SDK-Android/amity-push-fcm/6.10.0/amity-push-fcm-6.10.0.pom
> - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/github/AmityCo/Amity-Social-Cloud-SDK-Android/amity-push-fcm/6.10.0/amity-push-fcm-6.10.0.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/AmityCo/Amity-Social-Cloud-SDK-Android/amity-push-fcm/6.10.0/amity-push-fcm-6.10.0.pom
> - https://www.jitpack.io/com/github/AmityCo/Amity-Social-Cloud-SDK-Android/amity-push-fcm/6.10.0/amity-push-fcm-6.10.0.pom
> - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/AmityCo/Amity-Social-Cloud-SDK-Android/amity-push-fcm/6.10.0/amity-push-fcm-6.10.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :app